# How to provide persistent redis pubsub

Tags: node.js, redis, message

I am working on nodes socket.io redis project.

The real time instant message works fine. However, I am wondering how to store offline message and how to guarantee message delivery.

Anyone has idea on how to implement persistent pub sub using above tech stack ?

Cheers
Homer

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of message you want to handle.
Take a look [here](http://redis.io/topics/persistence), and I would advice to use AOF style.
And if you need something bigger then your RAM, I would recommend to delete message from the queue when its delivered to receiver, and then copy it to some MySQL/MongoDB/Riak/WhateverDB you like.

How is that sounds to you?